# Supercollider ERROR: can't set a control to a UGen

Tags: supercollider

I am trying to change the volume using Line.kr but I get this error: ERROR: can't set a control to a UGen

Here is the code:

```
a = {arg freq=440, vol=0; SinOsc.ar(freq)*vol}.play
a.set(\vol,Line.kr(0,1.0,3))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually such a basic issue/topic that a more elaborate answer is perhaps warranted. Basically, if you need/want "total flexibility" in what that `\vol` envelope is, you have to read it from a (server-side) bus or use one of the many client-side wrapper tricks that hide that (bus) plumbing under some syntactic sugar. A typical example of the latter would be JITLib. An example using the latter:

```
a = Ndef(\a, {arg freq=440, vol=0; SinOsc.ar(freq)*vol}).play;
a.set(\vol, Ndef(\v, { Line.kr(0,1.0,3) }))
```

If you now do `a.edit` you'll see somthing like

[image]

Without using that JITLib sugar, you'd have allocate and map a bus yourself, such as in:

```
a = {arg freq=440, vol=0; SinOsc.ar(freq)*vol}.play;
b = Bus.control(s, 1); // "s" is the default-bound server variable
a.map(\vol, b);
c = { Out.kr(b, Line.kr(0,1.0,3);) }.play;
```

With JITlib you can just `set` all over as it has "smarts" to detect the argument type, but with the basic SC you need to distinguish between mapping and setting... although you can also set something to a c-led bus-number string to achieve the same effect (`map` basically does that for you), i.e. the penultimate line above can be `a.set(\vol, b.asMap);` Just `b.asMap` evaluates to something like e.g. "c1", meaning control bus 1. (Audio busses use "a" prefixes instead, as you might expect.)

---

This bit may be somewhat more confusing, but keeping in mind that `a` and `~a` are different types of variables (more or less function stack vs environment stack), the `Ndef` keys (first `Ndef` arguments) can be used "directly" in "shortcut" ~variables provided by the `ProxySpace` as in

```
p = ProxySpace.push(s);
~a = {arg freq=440, vol=0; SinOsc.ar(freq)*vol};
~a.play;  // play the NodeProxy, not the Function (Synth) directly
~a.set(\vol, ~v); // ~v is a NodeProxy.nil(localhost, nil) due to ProxySpace
~v = { Line.kr(0,1.0,3) };
```

Under the hood this last example practically auto-issues `Ndef`s, i.e the 2nd line does the same as `Ndef(\a ...`, so you don't have to type `Ndefs` explicitly anymore. The way this works is that `ProxySpace` replaces the `currentEnvironment` (where ~variables live) with one in which `put`, which is triggered by assignments to ~variables, is now creating or modifying `Ndef`s and `at` is accessing them, e.g. if you evaluate `currentEnvironment` now it shows something like

`ProxySpace ( ~a - ar(1)         ~v - kr(1) )`

(To get back to your prior environment issue a `p.pop` now.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use UGen to set some arg of a SynthDef, but you can set the arguments of Line.kr:

```
a = {arg freq=440, vol=0; SinOsc.ar(freq)*Line.kr(atk,sus,rel)}.play
a.set(\atk,0,\sus,1,\rel,0)
```

please note that with Line.kr you can't restart the envelope.
For a more specific control please see the EnvGen UGen:
http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/EnvGen.html

Comment: In the first line, that needs to be `Line.kr(\atk.kr, \sus.kr, \rel.kr)` otherwise you're not making any controls (and you'll also get an error for undeclared variables in that example). You can (later) `set` controls that don't exist alas, it's just that nothing happens in that case.

Comment: And the params for `Line` are really `(start, end, dur)`.